# Angular2 Maximum number of FormGroup controls in a FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular2-forms

We have a FormArray that contains many FormGroups.  This was intended to hold roughly 20 items or less.  Now the designer wants to add > 300 items to the array and the code is taking >30s for each `<FormArray>this.controls['arrayName'].push(this.fb.group({list,of,controls}))` call.  I'm assuming we've just hit the limit of what this data structure can hold and need to re-design the form to store the data with fewer FormControls?

edit:  It seems to be `updateValueAndValidity` that's causing it to take so slow.  If I push the controls onto `this.controls['arrayName'].controls` and then call `updateValueAndValidity` then it runs better/faster, but I don't know if I'm missing anything necessary because the Angular docs specifically say not to do this method.

Comment: are you using any impure pipes with your array?

Comment: @DavidLee No, I'm loading an array of JSON objects from a remote API and then creating a FormGroup object and pushing each object into the Angular FormArray.